# Scala - finding a specific key in an array of tuples

Tags: scala, search

So far I have an array of tuples that is filled with key,value pairs (keys are ints and values are strings).

```
val tuple_array = new Array[(K,V)](100)
```

I want to find a specific key in this array. So far I have tried:

```
tuple_array.find()
```

but this requires me to enter a key,value pair. (I think). I want to just search this array and see if the key exists at all and if it does either return 1 or true.(havent decided yet). I could just loop through the array but I was going for a faster runtime.

How would I go about searching for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but this requires me to enter a key,value pair. (I think).

No it doesn't, check the docs, you can just do:

```scala
tuple_array.find(_._1 == theKeyYouWant).map(_._2)
```

That returns an `Option[V]` with the value associated with the key if it was present. You then may just do an `isDefined` to return `true` if the key existed.

> could just loop through the array but I was going for a faster runtime.

Well `find` just loops.

You may want to use a `Map[K, V]` instead of an `Array[(K, V)]` and just use `contains`

---

Also, as personal advice, it seems you are pretty new to the language; I would recommend you to pick a course or tutorial. **Scala** is way more than syntax.

Comment: I am pretty new to the language. Appreciate the tips. Will look into more tutorials.

Comment: @JohnRon for starters I would invite you to join the official [**discord** server](https://discord.gg/ex9AstC3) where you may get more interactive help from multiple folks :D

Comment: I just did - Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[`find`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/ArrayOps.html#find(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option%5BA%5D) requires you to pass a predicate: function returning `true` if condition is fulfilled. You can use it e.g. like this:

```
tuple_array.find { tuple =>
  tuple._1 == searched_key
}
```

It doesn't require you to pass a tuple.

Since this is an array, you have to go through a whole array at worse case (O(n)), there is no faster way (asymptotically) unless your array is sorted and allows usage of a binary-search (which isn't a part of the interface as you never knows if a random array is sorted). Whether you'll do this by iterating manually or through `find` (or `collectFirst`) doesn't affect the speed much.